# Detecting click on inner div with event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation, event-delegation

I have an accordion that when it is clicked (the whole element) it triggers and displays the inner items. I want to be able to add an accordion inside of one of the inner items, so I'm using event.target to see where the click happens. For some reason, event.target detects the click on an inner paragraph, but not on it's wrapper div? What is the reason of this?

```
$(".gestion-accordion-wrap").on("click", function(event){

      var $target = $( event.target );

      if ( $target.is ( $(".gestion-inner-wrap p") ) ){

        var $innerWrap = $(".gestion-inner-wrap p").parent().parent();

        $innerWrap.children().eq(1).slideToggle(300); 
        $innerWrap.find(".mas-detalles-clickable-inner").toggleClass("clickable-spin");
        $innerWrap.find(".mas-detalles-after-inner").toggle();
        $innerWrap.find(".menos-detalles-after-inner").toggle();

        $innerWrap.find(".span-left-line").toggleClass("left-line-grow");

      } else {

  $(this).children().eq(1).slideToggle(300); 
  $(this).find(".mas-detalles-clickable").toggleClass("clickable-spin");
  $(this).find(".mas-detalles-after").toggle();
  $(this).find(".menos-detalles-after").toggle();
  $(this).find(".span-left-line").toggleClass("left-line-grow");
}})
```

Why is this detected:

```
if ( $target.is ( $(".gestion-inner-wrap p") ) ){
```

But not this?

```
if ( $target.is ( $(".gestion-inner-wrap") ) ){
```

(**NOTE :** There's no `p` in this selector)

Comment: Can't you just use .onclick

Comment: Can you post your HTML, at least the structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way DOM works ! .

[target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property is intended to match only that exact element on which a given event occurs , the *handler which caught the event doesn't matter*.What you need instead is **[currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)** property.

**currentTarget**

> Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

```
$(".gestion-accordion-wrap").on("click",'*',  function(event){

  var $target = $( event.currentTarget );
  alert( $target.is ( $(".gestion-inner-wrap") ) ); // TRUE

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mbzp2xcp/

Comment: I am not clear with the html can you post barebones html? Try adding '*' in `on()` see edit

Comment: I agree that it sounds like `currentTarget` is the appropriate solution. It's going to be hard to figure out why that isn't working without being able to reproduce the problem interactively.

Comment: Ye  unless he posts some fiddle or something it would be hard to exactly tell what the issue